# symfony2 assets targets the /www server folder, not the /web symfony folder when deploy in production

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, assets, production-environment

I have some problems with Symfony 2 application deployment. I have import all files I  need on my OVH shared server, but some errors occured like css and js files not found (internal server error for example) or error like `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://my-server/css/458dafd_bootstrap-theme.min_1.css"`.

Notice that I have installed the [CoresphereBundle](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle) in order to have a console in my browser when my application is iploaded on my server, I have access to the console only on dev environment.

This is step by step what I did in order to deploy my application:

**1** I updated my application and vendors with composer (because I have no ways to install composer on my server)

```
composer.phar update
```

**2** I clear the dev cache `php app/console cache:clear`

**3** I clear the prod cache `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

**4** I install assets `php app/console assets:install web`

**5** I dump the assets `php app/console assetic:dump web`

**6** I uploaded my symfony application on my server.

**7** Once the files are uploaded in `web/app.php` I I authorize
 the prod debug

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

**8** Then in `web/config.php` I remove this block

```
// …

if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
  '127.0.0.1',
  '::1',
))) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

So, on my server, if I would like to go to `http://my-server/web/config.php` it works well, so I see if my server is compatible with symfony. the only thing that appears is `Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.`

**9** I set the access rights for the `app/cache` and `app/log` folders to **777** on my server, it allows the applications to write in these folders.

**10** In `web/app_dev.php` I write this code, in order to allow the dev mode for my IP adress and so have access to the console bundle

```
// …

if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
  '127.0.0.1',
  '::1',
  '121.457.719.2' //a random ip adress it's just for you to understand
))) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

**11** So I have access to the dev environment on my server, all works well, and no errors occured here. To access to the console bundle, following to the bundle documentation, I have to wrote  `http://my-server/web/app_dev.php/_console` (see the routing code here):

```
_console:
    resource: "@CoreSphereConsoleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /_console
```

But this routes does not exist, If I wrote this url, nothing appear in my browser: [image]

However, by the `config.php`, I have access to `app_dev.php` by following the `Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page` link:

[image]

I click on the link and I arrived on `app_dev.php`. Like I said before, no errors occured in this environment, except for the console route. But I could have access to the console by clicking on the console logo under the symfony debug toolbar:
[image]

This is the url for the console when I click on the logo under symfony debug toolbar: `http://my-server/web/app_dev.php//_console/_console`, I would like to understand why?

Then when I would like to make some commands another error occured: `[error] Internal Server Error` in the console:
[image]

If I try to use the router debug `php app/console debug:router`, I have this:
[image]

and with the `php app/console debug:router | grep _console`:
[image]

So, there are the problems I have with my symfony application.

---

UPDATE

I resolved the problem of the console bundle. In fact my server does not use the same php version of my symfony application, I have to set this in the `.ovhconfig` at the root of my `/www` folder.
`/www/.ovhconfig`:

```
app.engine=php
app.engine.version=5.5
http.firewall=none
environment=production
```

Now when I would like to access to the production environment I have these errors concerning all my assets files (**css/js/images**, a 404 not found):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -> `http://my-server.com/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js`
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: fos is not defined -> routing:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   ->`http://my-server.com/css/45898d_dataTables.min_7.css`

I don't really understand, the files are indeed at the root of the app, e-g I have no folder css or js or etc in `http://my-server.com/`. These folders are in `http://my-server.com/web/`. Where is the problem?

When I access to the console, this is the command I made:

1 `cache:clear`

2 `assets:install web`

3 `assetic:dump web`

---

EDIT: solution works

I understand that the assets target a `/css` `/js` `/images` etc folder at the root of my server, so I replace the css and js files to the root of the `/www` server folder, e-g in the `/www` folder of my server I have this:

```
//my server
  /.ssh
  /www /*http://my-server.com/...*/
    /app/
    /bin/
    /css/
    /fonts/
    /images/
    /js/
    /src/
    /vendor/
    /web/
    /.htaccess
    /.ovhconfig
    /composer.json
    /composer.lock
    /composer.phar
```

Why my symfony application tagets the assets here?

Comment: I want to add a note here: If you take a look into this bundle `routing.yml` file you will notice that their routes are already prefixed with `_console/` [routing.yml](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing.yml). When you import this file you add `_console/` prefix once again - thus the output you get. You can simply omit the prefix.

Comment: @Artamiel Ok, I understand what you suggest me, so I remove the `_console` route in `routing_dev.yml`, but I have an error in a modal: **an error occured while loading the debug toolbar (error 500).**: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "console" as such route does not exist.") in CoreSphereConsoleBundle:Toolbar:toolbar.html.twig at line 5.`

Comment: No, you still need to import the file. Just try without the `prefix` part.

Comment: @Artamiel I follow your suggestion and it works, I have imported the route without the prefix section. It works, I have well the right route url. But, `[error] Internal Server Error` message still here when I submit  a command in the console

Comment: It could be for any reason. Have you tried looking at your logs? There should be something logged by monolog in `app/logs`.

Comment: @Artamiel nothing in the log could allow me to understand this. On my server when I am on dev environment I have this error in the console, but in local environment, no error in the console occured

Comment: Can you try changing _console to something else without the underscore and see if it works? Clear the cache after you do that and see if it worked. Use the route debuger again, see what you get. Maybe the underscore gives problems somehow.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc thank you for reply, I solved the problem with the `Console CoresphereBundle`, in fact my server does not use the same php version of my symfony application, I change that and now the **console cmd** work well. But I have always the problem of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for my assets **css/js/images files**. See my edit.

Comment: I found a solution, see my updated post. It disturbs me to do this in this way, I don't think it's the right solution but for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Symfony command line routing debugger?

`php app/console debug:router`

That will output all the routes the symfony app knows about and you could try piping it into `grep` to see if you're trying to use the wrong path to hit the _console route.

`php app/console debug:router | grep _console`

Comment: thank you for answering me, see my edit in my initial question, I have tried your suggestion.

Comment: I found a solution, see my updated post. It disturbs me to do this in this way, I don't think it's the right solution but for now it works.

Comment: I think the mismatch with your expectations is that symfony expects the web/ directory to be the public folder (what www/ is playing now) and that is why your assets are not found when they're placed in web/. I am not familiar with how OVH works, but can you put your symfony app one directory higher and expose the symfony web/ directory the same way that www/ is exposed now?